# How to use Quads in MDX Parallel period function - Not Quarters

Tags: mdx

Hi I have created a time dimension like below:

[image: Time Dimension Table]

Here i am considering the 4 Weeks as one Quad (In a year we will get total 13 Quads)
, I Need to use the Quad in MDX Paralle period function, When i select the current quad it needs to take the last year same quad and needs to dispaly the data.

The Dimesion like below:

[image: Time Dimension]

To Achive the same i have used the quad in MDX and passed the int value as 13, but not worked for me.

As Per @FrankPI

I wrote the MDX Query like below:

```
with member [Measures].[pycomp]
as
ParallelPeriod ([DimTime].[Time].[Year], 1, [DimTime].[Time].[Quad].CurrentMember)


select [Measures].[pycomp] on 0,
[DimTime].[Time].[Year].&[2012].&[Quad 07 (2012)] on 1
from [Cube]
```

I am getting the error as i said in the below comments "#Error".

When i click on the cell it showint the below msg.

[image: MDX Error Message]

CellOrdinal : 0

VALUE      :   #Error Query (3, 45) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used.

FORMATTED_VALUE : #Error Query (3, 45) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used.

Any help is apprecieated.

Thanks,
Roshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Year], 1, [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember)
```

should deliver you the quad one year before the current one. The first argument is the level to use as the reference (`year` in this case), the second the number of reference periods (in this case years) to go back, and the third argument is the reference point, normally on a lower level than the reference level.

**Edit**

According to your edited query, and assuming you did not rename `DimTime` in the cube object, this should be as follows:

```
 ParallelPeriod ([DimTime].[Time].[Year], 1, [DimTime].[Time].CurrentMember)
```

Comment: Hi @FrankPI, sorry for the dealy, it is not working for me, When I use the above query I am getting "#Error". Any other idea...

Comment: If you are using Management Studio to test this in an MDX query, you can double click the cell to get details about the error, which in many cases references a row and column of your query or the cube calculation script. Post your query or the relevant statement in the cube calculation script together with the error message.

Comment: @FrankPI As it showing that the issue with "[Date].[Calendar].[Quad].CurrentMember", Here cant use the [Quad].Currentmember

Comment: Are you using an user hierarchy? Is it named `[Date].[Calendar]`? If not, what is its name? How is the `Quad` level named? Without seeing any of the names in your cube, I just need to guess, and you will need to transfer my guesses to the real names within your cube.

Comment: @FrankPI Yes, I am using Hierarchy. I have added table & dimesion images to the original question. Can you please have a look and suggest ?

Comment: @FrankPI I have converted your first example to the same code taht you have suggested after my screen shot of the hierarchy, Here i have attached my mdx query and the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the second parameter should have been `[DimTime].[Time].CurrentMember` without the `[Quad]`, thus `ParallelPeriod ([DimTime].[Time].[Year], 1, [DimTime].[Time].CurrentMember)`.